# Excluding metadata when generating a pdf file checksum in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I intend to generate a checksum on the file then I put the checksum as metadata of the file itself. However, the problem I faced was that the checksum generated before and after the metadata was placed in the file is different, I realized that this happened because the metadata in the file was changed.
And this is what I did with PyPDF2 in Python 3 :

```
import os
import sys
import time
import hashlib

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import NameObject, createStringObject
```

**1. Function to generate MD5 Checksum of a file**

```
def md5_checksum(filePath):
    try:
        with open(filePath, 'rb') as file:
            m = hashlib.md5()
            while True:
                data = file.read(8192)
                if not data:
                    break

                m.update(data)

            return m.hexdigest()
    except IOError:
        print('[ERROR][NOT FOUND]: ' + filePath)
        return 'NULL'
    finally:
        file.close()
```

**2. Function to embedd metadata to PDF file**

```
def embedd_metadata_file(file_in, file_out, metadatas):
    with open(file_in, 'rb') as fin:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(fin)
        writer = PdfFileWriter()
        metadata = writer._info.getObject()
        info = pdf.documentInfo

        for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
            writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

        for key in info:
            metadata.update({NameObject(key): createStringObject(info[key])})

        for key in metadatas:
            metadata.update({NameObject(key): createStringObject(str(metadatas[key]))})

        metadata.update({
            NameObject('/Pages'): createStringObject(str(pdf.getNumPages()))
        })

        with open(file_out, 'wb') as fout:
            writer.write(fout)

    fin.close()
    fout.close()

    os.unlink(file_in)
    os.rename(file_out, file_in)

    pdf = PdfFileReader(open(file_in, 'rb'))
    return pdf.getDocumentInfo()
```

**3. Call the function**

```
file = 'example.pdf'
file_in = os.path.join(DIR, file)
file_out = os.path.join(DIR, file + '.OUT.pdf')

checksum = md5_checksum(file_in)
metadata = embedd_metadata_file(file_in, file_out, {
    '/MD5Checksum': checksum,
    '/ISBN': 'xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxx',
    '/eISBN': 'xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxx,
    '/Title': 'Blablablabla',
    '/Size': '2.3 MB',
    '/Author': 'Some Author',
    '/Copyright': 'Blabla Blablabla',
    '/Version': '2',
    '/Publisher': 'Blablablabla Blabla'
})
```

The question is, how can I put the checksum as metadata file without changing the checksum of the file itself? Any help I appreciate it.

Comment: I have asked a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566153/how-do-i-calculate-the-md5-checksum-of-a-file-contents-in-python

My solution is, I have extracted all text from the pdf file and calculate the md5 checksum on that content which gives me result what I want but PyPdf2 is not good with the password-protected pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it how the NIX package manager does it. You insert 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' as the hash, checksum the file and then replace that with the real hash. When the file is checked you replace the hash with the X's and hash the file.

But I wouldn't do this with PDFs. For PDFs it would be better to sign them.