# How do I calculate the MD5 checksum of a file contents in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, md5, hashlib

the scenario is: I have generated md5 checksum for the pdf file which stored on the server using the following code:

```
 def createMd5Hash(self, file_path, pdf_title, pdf_author):
    md5_returned = None
    try:
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_to_check:
            for chunk in file_to_check:
                md5.update(chunk)
            md5_file = md5.hexdigest()
            custom_key = 'xyzkey-{}'.format(md5_file)
            md5.update(custom_key.encode())
            md5_returned = md5.hexdigest()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error while calculate md5: {}".format(e))
  
    # code to add Hash value in metadata
    try:
        file = open(file_path, 'rb+')
        reader = PdfFileReader(file)
        writer = PdfFileWriter()
        writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
        metadata = reader.getDocumentInfo()
        writer.addMetadata(metadata)
        writer.addMetadata({
            '/Author': pdf_author,
            '/Title': pdf_title,
            '/HashKey': md5_returned,
        })
        writer.write(file)
        file.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Error while editing metadata")
```

example: HashKey = 02c85672c041c8c762474799690ad1a5

In the second part, I have added the metadata, including the hash value in the pdf.
Now clients can download this file from my server (can be modified by them or not).
When I received the file from any of my clients, I want to check the integrity of that file. Weather file data is modified or not. So for that, I wrote a utility that uploads the file and extract the metadata of the pdf file where I can get HashKey value which is the original hash value of the file when it was generating.
When I try to decode the file using the following function, I suppose to get the same hash value if it's just downloaded from the server and not modified by my client.

```
def validateMd5Hash(file_path, current_md5):
md5_returned = None
try:
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_to_check:
        # read contents of the file
        for chunk in file_to_check:
            md5.update(chunk)
        # pipe contents of the file through
        md5_file = md5.hexdigest()
        private_key = 'xyzkey-{}'.format(md5_file)
        md5.update(private_key.encode())
        md5_returned = md5.hexdigest()

    if md5_returned != current_md5:
        return True

    return False
except Exception as e:
    print("Error while calculate md5: {}".format(e))
```

but the result is different.
md5_returned = fbf79424a68892887379108a05968437
current_md5 = 02c85672c041c8c762474799690ad1a5

When I use the above function, it generates different hash value then what it has during creation.
I guess the reason would be when the client downloads the file, created date and modified date change which is the reason I got new md5 checksum other than what is inside the HashKey.
I am looking to generate a hash value for only the content of the file without includes metadata.
Can anyone help me, please?
Sorry for bad English

Comment: Perhaps I've misread your code, but you've overwritten your file with a file that has the metadata included.  So naturally, the hash file is different.

Comment: In your current approach, the metadata of the pdf is included in the hash calculations. Thus, when you calculate the hash after modifying hte metadata, it will be different. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860411/excluding-metadata-when-generating-a-pdf-file-checksum-in-python